# XFCE not responsive after attaching usb devices

Tags: ubuntu, usb, xfce, xfwm4

I am running Ubuntu with XFCE.

After I plug in a USB device (mouse, keyboard, headset) the system becomes unresponsive for 5-20 seconds (windows do not focus, resizing windows does not redraw content of windows of some programs (Thunderbird, Firefox, terminal xfce4-terminal does redraw), mouse works, keyboard works) which was not happening before and is quite anoying. It also happens after waking up the system from sleep, there I have unresponsive system too.

I see that these two processes have high CPU usage:

1. /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
2. xfwm4 --replace

If I plug in only mouse it takes 3-5 seconds. If I plug in mouse and keyboard both via usb hub it takes 10-15 seconds.

/var/log/**Xorg.0.log** does not show anything weird - just information about plugged in devices, also the **dmesg** does show only information about the devices. **journalctl -f** either ( https://pastebin.com/eFr2XYgE ).

Where to look for the problem further?

Comment: Check `dmesg` and `journalctl -f` outputs as well.

Comment: Output from dmesg or journalctl does not show anything weird. Sometimes I see there error "rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command".

Comment: Do you have a `~/.Xmodmap`? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546116/input-devices-stop-responding-and-high-x-org-and-kglobalaccel5-cpu-usage-when-co